# Ant Design - How to wrap a Table into a Form.List in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

everyone. I have a task UI like this pic. The project team is using React and Ant design.

[image: picture]

This's first time i working with Antd so i don't know how shoudl i solve this task. I think i use a Table in a Form.List to display and handle use edit.

But i can't find any example code like that on anywhere. If you was solved problem like that, please show me a code sandbox link or any thing else.

Thanks for reading my problem.

Comment: No, you don't need to wrap it in a Form.List. Antd's `Table` component allows [editable cells](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell). If you look at the code, they created a custom `EditableCell` component that takes a `handleSave` prop and uses it to save the table's data state.